# Two IQ test patterns

Tags: pattern

The following are two patterns found at this [IQ test site](http://lv.iq-test.cc/). What are the rules of the left panel and which square from the right panel should replace the question mark?

Pattern 1:

[image: Pattern 1]

Pattern 2:

[image: Pattern 2]

Comment: Are those 3x3 patterns, or 3 examples of 3x1 patterns (rows/columns?)?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pattern 1 (credit to malioboro):

> The answer is the **middle top.** 
>  The left part in the third image is formed by adding the contents of the left part of the first and second image, and the right part is subtracting the first image with the second image.

Pattern 2:

> The answer is the **middle bottom.** 
>  We can observe that the sides are increasing on each row (starting from 3). We ignore the position of the dots and count them instead. The rows contain exactly 3 to 5 dots.

Answer (score 4):

Pattern 1:

> Each row, add contents of the left part of the first image with the left part of the second image to get the left part of the third image
>
>  then subtract the right part of the first image by the right part of the second image to get the right part of the third image
>
>  Answer: B (MIDDLE TOP)

Pattern 2 (different approach than @shoover and @u_ndefined's answer)

> I found a different answer for this pattern, first try to analyze the number of dots inside/outside:
>
> ```
> col 1 2 3
>     -----
>     0 1 1  // OUTSIDE
>     1 0 0  // INSIDE
>
>     0 0 1  // OUTSIDE
>     1 1 1  // INSIDE
>
>     0 1 ?  // OUTSIDE
>     3 0 ?  // INSIDE
> ```
>
> From the pattern above, the number of dot outside of third column image is always 1. And the number of dot inside can be calculated by `#Dot inside the first column image - #Dot outside the second column image` and it will give you number dot inside the third image of the third row is 2
>
>   So, another answer for Pattern 2: A (TOP LEFT)

Comment: Nice and quick answer to A. Nice alternative answer to B. +1

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer, pattern 2:

> The top row is all triangles, the middle row is all quadrilaterals, and therefore the bottom row is all pentagons, so it is one of the pentagons.
>
>
>  The row with three-sided figures has three dots total, the row with four-sided figures has four dots total, so the row with five-sided figures will have five dots total, so there is one dot.
>
>
>  It's the middle figure on the bottom row, the pentagon with one dot.